# python 2.7.6 math program

Tags: python-2.7

Ok, the Program that i need help with may not be that complex but I'm beyond confused on it. Here are my instructions:

Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer then figures out how many integers (from 1 up) you have to add up in order for the total to be greater than the value that the user entered.  That is, find the number "n" such that the sum of the integers from 1 to n is greater than the value that the user entered, but the sum of the integers from 1 to (n-1) is less than or equal to the value that the user entered.  Your output should be a descriptive message including the number n and the sum of the numbers from 1 to n;  Something like:

Please enter an integer: 1000
Summing the integers from 1 to 45 gives 1035

I have gotten this far:
     inp = input ('Please enter an integer. ')
If you could point me in the right direction, that would be great. 
EDIT:

How could i get this to print as well?

Edit:

I tried to alter the answer below to this:

```
n = input ('Please enter an integer. ')
sum = 0
i = 1
while sum < n:
    sum = i
    i + 1 = i
if sum > n:
    print 'Summing the integers from 1 to ' + i + 'gives' + sum
```

I get an error that says that i cant assign to operator in line six

Comment: `i = i + 1` or `i += 1`. You also shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name because there is already a function `sum()` in the standard Python library.

Answer (score 0):

well there is the obvious way and a more clever way
the obvious way is to add number until they are greater:

```
sum = 0
i = 1
while sum < inp:
    sum += i
    i += 1
```

the sum of numbers 1 to n is given by n * (n+1) / 2 so you can solve for n given inp you'll probably want the positive root